# Django CreateView : Append ForeignKey to CustomForm Data

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, form-data, create-view

I have a CreateView as follows:

```
class ResumeCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Resume

    def form_valid(self, request, form):
        candidate = Candidate.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.candidate = candidate
        self.object.save()
        f = self.request.FILES.get('file')
        data = [{
            'title': self.request['title'],
            'name': f.name,
        }]  
        response = JSONResponse(data, {}, response_mimetype(self.request))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
        return response
```

here i am trying to append the `candidate` instance to the `Resume` models candidate field which is a `ForeignKey` to the `Candidate` model.

But i always receive validation error `{'candidate' : 'This field is required'}`

- I am using a custom form not a model form as it uses twitter bootstrap identifiers.

what am i missing ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will have to define a `modelForm` with `candidate` as excluded field and then set it in `form_valid()` method.

```
class ResumeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Resume
        exclude = ('candidate',)

class ResumeCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = ResumeForm
    model = Resume

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.candidate = Candidate.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        ....
```

More detailed reference at: [Models and request.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user)

Comment: Hey Rohan, i am aware that it works with a ModelForm, sorry i forgot to mention that i am using a Custom form. Is there a work around for Custom Forms. ?

Comment: @Amyth, I don't think it will work without defining a model form as suggested. Without that django framework will create form that requires `candidate` field as well, which is not present when you POST.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough karma to comment but i just wanted to note that this worked for my problem & my only variation (on Rohan's answer) was that i didn't need to create a form.

`class ChoiceCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Choice
    template_name = 'polls/choice.html'
    fields = ['choice_text']`

instead i specify the fields i do want to show in my view rather than exclude them in a form. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this exact issue before. For a quick fix, include the candidate in your form using a hidden input, like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="candidate" id="id_candidate" value="{{ request.user.id }}">
```

In the future, though, consider using [django-crispy-forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms) instead of writing your forms by hand.

Comment: This is a bad idea: you should set such fields on the server side, e.g. in the view's POST. Users may submit a different user id and you just don't want that to happen.